# Keyboard is not at the bottom

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jframe, layout-manager

I'm running this in IntelliJ and the keyboard should be at the bottom (`this.getContentPane().add(keyboard, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`) but it's stuck above the center and resizes my textfields way too small. Why is it acting that way?
[image: keyboard]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

    public class GameGUI extends JFrame
    {
        private final JPanel letters; // for textfields
        private final JPanel keyboard; // for buttons
        private final JTextField [][] tfs; // array for textfields
        private final JButton[] top, home, bottom; // buttons for rows
        private final String[] topRow = {"Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"};
        private final String[] homeRow = {"A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"};
        private final String[] bottomRow = {"Enter", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", "Backspace"};
    
        public GameGUI()
        {
            this.setSize(350, 450);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 5));
    
            letters = new JPanel();
            letters.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 5));
    
            tfs = new JTextField[6][5];
            JPanel letterPlaceholder = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 5));
            for(int r = 0; r < 6; r++)
            {
                for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
                {
                    JTextField board = new JTextField(String.valueOf(tfs[r][c]));
                    tfs[r][c] = board;
                    letterPlaceholder.add(tfs[r][c]);
                }
            }
            letters.add(letterPlaceholder);
    
            keyboard = new JPanel();
            keyboard.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    
            // top row
            top = new JButton[topRow.length];
            JPanel keys = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, topRow.length));
            for(int i = 0; i < topRow.length; i++)
            {
                JButton topsize = new JButton(topRow[i]);
                top[i] = topsize;
                keys.add(top[i]);
            }
            keyboard.add(keys);
    
            // home row
            home = new JButton[homeRow.length];
            keys = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, homeRow.length));
            for(int i = 0; i < homeRow.length; i++)
            {
                JButton homesize = new JButton(homeRow[i]);
                home[i] = homesize;
                keys.add(home[i]);
            }
            keyboard.add(keys);
    
            // bottom row
            bottom = new JButton[bottomRow.length];
            keys = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, bottomRow.length));
            for(int i = 0; i < bottomRow.length; i++)
            {
                JButton bottomsize = new JButton(bottomRow[i]);
                bottom[i] = bottomsize;
                keys.add(bottom[i]);
            }
            keyboard.add(keys);
    
            this.getContentPane().add(letters, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            this.getContentPane().add(keyboard, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            new GameGUI();
        }
    }
```

I experimented around and commented this code (and other lines that is needed for this part) out to see if maybe that was the problem:

```
letters = new JPanel();
letters.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 5));

tfs = new JTextField[6][5];
JPanel letterPlaceholder = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 5));
for(int r = 0; r < 6; r++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    {
        JTextField board = new JTextField(String.valueOf(tfs[r][c]));
        tfs[r][c] = board;
        letterPlaceholder.add(tfs[r][c]);
    }
}
letters.add(letterPlaceholder);
```

But then it acts like this:
[image]

What's even weirder is that I had the same code as I have currently for the keyboard days ago and it was working fine. I'm either doing something wrong or it's something that has to do with IntelliJ.

Comment: Get rid of `this.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 5));` and make use of the fact that `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the conflicting lines where I use `GridLayout` and `BorderLayout`. I assign `GridLayout` to JFrame but use `BorderLayout` to align the components.

The small fix was changing `this.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 5));`
to `this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());`. But I'm still not too sure on why it was working before..

Edit: `this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` would also just be unnecessary to add, so I could better yet just remove the line completely